# Is it okay to do all these jQuery things to a React.js DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I recently started using [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) and [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) for a project of mine, and I'm using jQuery too, for some parts of the GUI. Via jQuery, I sometimes add CSS classes and styles and even DOM nodes to elements created and updated by React. This seems to work just fine. React doesn't complain, and, when `render()` re-runs, React doesn't modify the classes and styles and the DOM nodes that has been added somewhere deep inside a react root.

- Can I rely on React ignoring DOM nodes I've added side by side with React DOM nodes inside a React tree? — I understand that the non-React nodes will be removed, if React decides to remove the node into which I inserted them. This is fine with me. But I do wonder if React some day in the future will get upset on these additional nodes not managed by React, and refuse to work?
- If React doesn't manage any styles of a DOM node (I haven't added any `style` attribute to the nodes generated by `render()`), then can I via jQuery safely add my own styles to this DOM node? E.g. look up a node by `#id` in jQuery and then set its width.
- If there's no `className` on a DOM node generated by React, can I then safely via jQuery add and remove classes to this node? (For example, add a class on mouse hover.)

One reason I'm currently doing these possibly weird things, is that I have some jQuery soup legacy code that I don't want to port to React right now. Another is that I'm using some jQuery plugins that sometimes add DOM nodes inside the React tree.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That sounds fine, but there are some rules you need to follow (and you can only use plugins that follow these rules):

- **don't** remove/replace/move any nodes React creates
- **don't** create siblings to React nodes, especially between or before react nodes
- **do** create nodes, add event listeners, modify dom in `componentDidMount` and/or `componentDidUpdate`
- **do** remove nodes, remove event listeners, in `componentWillUnmount`
- **do** create and append nodes manually in `componentDidMount` to pass to jQuery plugins
- **don't** modify DOM outside of react components
- **do** pass a callback to `setState` (argument 2) to do something after react updates it (but prefer `componentDidUpdate`)

For manually mounted React components (via `React.render`)

- **don't** mount a react component as a child of a plugin controlled element with no lifecycle hooks
- **do** use `React.unmountComponentAtNode` to clean up React components before removing their parent from the DOM
- **do** pass a callback to React.render (argument 3) if you *must* do something after the component is mounted

Please edit the question if I missed anything, or included a rule you feel is invalid.

Comment: I do create a sibling node, but I append it. I imagine inserting something inbetween React managed nodes might make React rather confused, as you indicated. I wonder if I can assume React will ignore sibling nodes that I've appended though (rather than inserted). If you have any links to any docs about this I'd be interested.

Comment: Hmm, you wrote "That sounds fine", and then "don't modify DOM outside of react components". Isn't that what my old jQuery code does, when it adds CSS classes and sets style attributes, on React nodes? Still this seems to work fine (I haven't specified `className` or `style` on these React nodes, so I suppose React never reads the values of these attributes, so it won't notice what jQuery has done (?)).

Comment: The problem with that is if React unmounts and mounts the nodes you've modified, you have no way to know unless you're doing it from the lifecycle hooks.  With appending siblings you may get errors when things are unmounted/updated because React encounters unknown nodes.  This stuff isn't documented anywhere official, but you can find various tutorials and StackOverflow questions with working code and patterns you can follow.